# iOS: Main.storyboard references the initial view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I'm adding a new storyboard reference:

[image]
But I'm getting this error:

```
error: Main.storyboard references the initial view controller of newStoryBoard.storyboard, but no designated entry point was found.
```

any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a storyboard reference, pointing to another storyboard named `newStoryBoard`. For the segue to work, it needs to know which view controller it should open from that storyboard.

Open `newStoryBoard.storyboard`, select the appropriate view controller, and check the **Is Initial View Controller** box in the properties panel on the right:

[image: checkbox]

Alternatively, you can set the **Referenced Id** in the storyboard reference properties. Set it to the storyboard Id of the view controller you want to open, and you should be all set.

Comment: How can I set Initial View Controller programmatically, ideally in prepare for segue code?

Comment: You can create different segues pointing to different VCs in the destination storyboard. Add identifiers for those in Interface Builder. You'd need to use the alternative solution at the bottom of my answer. Then you can programmatically choose the segue you need and call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in your code.

Comment: Its work for me set a viewcontroller as Initial view controller.